# Replaceall JSON in Groovy for Jenkins

Tags: json, jenkins, groovy

hoping you all ok and your family as well, i need to ask something kinda noob.  I'm working right now with Groovy for some proyect in jenkins.   My json file has a lot names: "Ingress_1", "Ingress_2" and so on, so i'll try with the famous replaceAll but nothing happens:

Here's the code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
if(the_suite.equals("Asset_important"))
{
def process =["cat",".blabla/jsonfile.json"].execute()
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
List<String> artifacts = new ArrayList<String>()
def object_a = jsonSlurper.parseText(process.text)
def object = object_a.replaceAll(/_/, ' ')

assert object instanceof Map
for(i=0;i<object.data.size();i++){        artifacts.add(object.data[i].feature)
 }
```

I already tried with `replaceAll("/_/", ' ')`

Thanks for read this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replaceAll()` is only defined for `String`, but you are trying to use it on the result of `JsonSlurper.parseText()`, which is of type `Object`.

This should work:

```
def object = jsonSlurper.parseText(process.text.replaceAll('_', ' '))
```

Comment: thanks!, i didnt read this and it helps a lot now jajaj sry!